# Icon color in image view set to grey and unable to change the color Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have included an icon in the image view which original color is white but after implementing it , the color changes to lite grey

**Drawable XML**

*ic_baseline_settings_24.xml*

> Note: I have not include path data because otherwise the code will get
> long

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
</vector>
```

**Layout XML**

*snipet_profile.xml*

> ImageView Tag is at the end of the layout if you want to skip to it
> directly

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProfileName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/sagar_raval"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PostCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:text="@string/_150"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ProfileName"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FollowersCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:text="@string/_100k"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/PostCount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ProfileName"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FollowingsCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:text="@string/_500"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/FollowersCount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ProfileName"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Post"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:text="@string/posts"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PostCount" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Followers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/followers"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Post"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/FollowersCount"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Following"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/following"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Followers"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/FollowingsCount"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_red"
        android:text="@string/edit_profile"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Followers"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/account_Settings"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Following"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Which color `?attr/colorControlNormal` is?

Comment: i have changed the tint to white but still, it didn't change the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `tint` overrides every other color-related attribute so either use `tint` to color the item white or remove that attribute for `fillColor` to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"` from your code